# Oracle multiple Sessions

Tags: c#, oracle11g

I have created service using c# language, it is working properly but problem is there with database session. Session should be created once at the time of log-in, and same session should be maintained till application is not closed or service is not stopped.
But in my case at the time of log-in a session is created, but same session is not maintained through out the process, new sessions are being created, which should not happen.
It should created one session at log-in time, and should use the same session until application is not closed.
What could be the cause that it is creating new session for the same database connection and not using the already created session. 
Event i have closed and disposed the database connection objects carefully.
I dont want sessions to be created. 
Reply ASAP as it slowing down server.
Suggestions and answers are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Why there is such a restriction ?

Since its web;  each request served by a thread in this case you might want to make your connection singleton but best practise is:  closing connection after your work done. and pooling would be helpfull also.

An idea : What about if you enable connection pooling and set max poolsize to 1. I dont have any Oracle Db close to me.  But worth to try i suppose.

Check out this SO questions:

[Storing connection in a static class (ASP.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383551/storing-connection-in-a-static-class-asp-net)

[Is using a singleton for the connection a good idea in ASP.NET website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557592/is-using-a-singleton-for-the-connection-a-good-idea-in-asp-net-website)

[Sharing single database connection between several methods simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222131/sharing-single-database-connection-between-several-methods-simultaneously)